# how to return a button after DOM with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, dom

I want to ask here I try to make HTML manipulation where when the button is clicked it will send data to ajax, before ajax gives a response then the button will be disabled, the problem here is I want to restore the button back to the beginning how to do?
There is my HTML

```
<button
  type="button"
  href=""
  id="bank"
  query-string="{{$assessment['user_id'].'&type=bank&name=american'}}"
  data-toggle="tooltip"
  data-placement="bottom"
  title=""
  data-original-title="Detail Mutation Bank BCA"
  class="btn btn-soft-dark mt-1 mr-1"
>
  mutation
</button>

<script>
  var bank = $("#bank").attr("query-string");
  var btnText = $(this);
  var btn = $(this);
  $(btn)
    .html(
      `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>`
    )
    .attr("disabled", true);

  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{route('getDescription')}}" + "?id=" + bank,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.status == "error") {
        createAlert(data.message, "danger");
      } else {
        window.open(data.url, "_blank");
      }
    }
    //here i want to restore button
  });
</script>
```

Comment: keep a copy of the button in a variable and then assign the same button content to yout `btn` variable.. But that would be most dirty solution.. I would suggest you to keep 2 buttons.. One with the content you need when you do `ajax` call and other one as original button, so that you can hide and show these buttons accordingly..

Comment: You should enable button in both the success and error callback of the ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the previous HTML content to `rootTextOfButton` value like

```
var rootTextOfButton = $(this).html();
```

Then you can restore like

```
btn.html(rootTextOfButton); //here i want to restore button
```

Besides, You should also remove `disabled` attribute like `btn.removeAttr("disabled");`

**Full code**

```
var rootTextOfButton = $(this).html();

var  btn = $(this);
        $(btn).html(`<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>`).attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"{{route('getDescription')}}"+"?id="+bank,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
            if(data.status=='error'){
                createAlert(data.message, "danger");
            }else{
                window.open(data.url, '_blank');
            }
         btn.html(rootTextOfButton); //here i want to restore button
         btn.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

Comment: `//here i want to restore button`. This would throw him an error. You are keeping it out of `success` function of `ajax`. Please correct accodingly..

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao  Updated, please take a look at :)

Comment: That looks good.. :) You can also add `error` scenario as suggested in one of the above comments to handle negative cases..

Comment: My pleasure.. Happy coding.. +1 :)